# How to check that how many time msg.sender is in array of smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm trying to make a smart contract in where anybody can donate to the specific center/ account. And after that they will get some points. Like points will be add according to their sending time. If someone send 2 times this person will get 20 points. But I'm unable to do that.
Because whenever I tried to send from different address the points does not changed. In fact, it's added to the previous points which was achieved by someone else.
something like , person 'A' donate 3 times and 'A' got 30 points.
Then person 'B' donate 1 time . 'B' should get 10 points. But 'B' got 40 points.That means
30+10 = 40.

**Here is my smart contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContract{
    
    struct Center{
        uint id;
        uint balance;
    }
    mapping(uint => Center) public center;
    uint count;
    
    address[100] public sender;
    uint countDown;
    
    uint public bonus;
    uint checkAddress;
    uint public a;
    
    constructor() public{
        addCenter(1,0);
        addCenter(2,0);
    }
    
    function addCenter(uint _id,uint amount) private{
        count++;
        center[count] = Center(_id, amount);
    }
    
    function sendMoney(uint centerId, uint _amount) payable public{
        require(centerId >0 && centerId <= count);
        
        countDown++;
        bonus+=10;
        
        sender[countDown] = msg.sender;
        
        if(centerId == 1){
            center[centerId].balance += _amount;
        }
        if(centerId == 2){
            center[centerId].balance += _amount;
        }
        

    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `bonus` is a global variable which is incremented by 10 each time the `sendMoney` method is called, regardless of the function caller.

If you want to track the bonus points from specific accounts you should use a mapping structure :

- Replace `uint public bonus;` by `mapping(address => uint256) public senderToBonus;`.
- In `sendMoney`  replace `bonus+=10;` by `senderToBonus[msg.sender]+=10;`.

Comment: Oh great. Now it's working perfectly..